# Getting a random track

Tags: python, soundcloud

Is there a way to get a random track from soundcloud API ? A work around I was thinking of also is getting a the total number of tracks, and picking a random number. But I can't find the way to get the total number of tracks either.

At the moment I am just wrapping the thing in a try/except, but then I do useless requests. If there's a way to avoid that !?

```
while (not track):
    try:
        track = client.get('/tracks/%s' % random.randint(0, 100000))
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        logger.error(e)
```

Comment: You may be able to get to abuse the search portion of the `/tracks` call by passing in specific `q = <search term>` requests.

Comment: @sean unfortunately it seems that the `/tracks/` endpoint only yields (50) tracks ordered by creation date and hotness. See [API console](http://developers.soundcloud.com/console)

Comment: yep ... this is not less a hack than mine. And mine is a bit simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other requirements for the track you want to pick out? Doing a simple GET request on `/tracks` will return 50 track instances unless you specify a `limit`. You could just pick a random one out of that set?

```
import random
import soundcloud

client = soundcloud.Client(access_token='YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN')
tracks = client.get('/tracks')
track = random.choice(tracks)
```

Hope that helps! Otherwise comment and I'll edit my answer with more details.

Comment: Hi ! Problem with that method is that I will get hottest tracks first right ? And that I don't really want, cause that's not random.